Contour integral $\oint_{c}\frac{1}{z \left(1-(z+1) \sqrt{\frac{r}{z}}\right)}dz$
I am new to complex analysis and am trying to figure out the following contour integral:
$$
I = \oint_{\scr C}\frac{1}{z\left[1 - \left(z + 1\right) \sqrt{r/z}\,\right]}\,{\rm d}z
$$
where $0<r<1/4$ and $\scr C$ is the unit circle, if that seems relevant, though I am open to changing this to any other radius if I am mistaken as to where the poles are. My approach, which appears to be a standard method from the online tutorials I have found, is to use the Cauchy integral theorem and find the residues at the various poles. The denominator has two factors: $1/z$, which has a pole at $z=z_1$ with $z_1=0$, and $1/\left(1-(z+1) \sqrt{\frac{r}{z}}\right)$, for which I find 2 zeros $z=z_2$ and $z=z_3$, where $z_2=\frac{1}{2r}-1+\sqrt{\frac1r\left(\frac1r-4\right)}$ and $z_3=\frac{1}{2r}-1-\sqrt{\frac1r\left(\frac1r-4\right)}$ are solutions to a quadratic equation.
What I am worried about using this factorization is regarding the note from this video (the clip I am concerned about is from 3:00 to 3:50):
https://youtu.be/RYAHvV0JJaI?si=KzJ6_DgMpq6cPh0A&t=180
The key to being able to use the result here is that the rest of the function is analytic at that pole, which is not my case for $z=z_1$ since $z$ appears on the denominator of the square-root term.
Therefore, I tried to do the change of variable (the one I used to get a quadratic equation) $w=\sqrt{z}$, and I obtain the following (I believe I am correct about keeping the same contour $c$ since the domains for $z$ and $w$ appear to be the same, but I am not entirely sure):
$$I=\oint_{c}\frac{-2}{\sqrt{r}\left(w-w_1\right)\left(w-w_2\right)}dw$$
where $w_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4r}}{2\sqrt{r}}$ and $w_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4r}}{2\sqrt{r}}$. In this case, I think the two poles are more obvious and satisfy the condition mentioned in the video regarding the function being analytic. Also, the poles appear to have non-zero residues for order $m=1$, and therefore I believe these are in fact first order poles. That said, when I sum both residues, the symmetry of the quadratic solutions yields a total of zero.
Therefore, I get $I=0$, but this seems incorrect:

this Wolfram Mathematica online notebook suggests the answer is $2\pi i\times 2\sqrt{5}$
the notebook, for the original integral on $z$, does not seem to solve...

My questions regarding this problem are: which portions of my approach are valid, if any? Are there any other insights I should be aware of? Where did I go wrong?

For one thing, the change of variables doesn't preserve the contour. Upon replacing $z\to e^{it}$ Mathematica suggests the actual value might be $i4\sqrt5(\pi-\cot^{-1}2)$ when $r=1/5$, and more generally$$-\frac{4i}{\sqrt{4r-1}}\left(\tanh^{-1}\frac{2\sqrt r-i}{\sqrt{4r-1}} + \tanh^{-1}\frac{2\sqrt r+i}{\sqrt{4r-1}}\right)$$

@user170231 thanks! how you obtain that general result remains a mystery to me (my software does not produce this when I clear r), I'll ponder on this for a bit; is it related to the fact that the contour changes? Because although I can see the contour changing with a change of variable, I do not see in this case how it affects the poles, which apparently (?) are the only concern in evaluating this type of integral. Also, is there any reason why Mathematica would prefer polar coordinates? Thanks again!

$\displaystyle,\sqrt{,{z},}$ is a multivalued function.

I could have sworn that's what Mathematica gave me when I first omitted the With (it took several seconds to compute), although now when I check again I get an equivalent but simpler result (notebook updated) for $0<r<1/4$ of$$\frac{2i}{\sqrt{1-4r}} \left(\pi + \tan^{-1}\frac2{\sqrt{\frac1r-4}}\right)$$

It would be nice to know what conditions $\color{red}{r}$ satisfy.

@FelixMarin I have edited the question indicating 0<r<1/4. As for your earlier comment regarding $\sqrt{z}$ being multivalued, it came on deaf ears because I simply did not understand what that entailed, but I just stumbled on this question which discusses a similar issue. This implies that one of the singularities is not a pole but requires a branch cut? I am very much a beginner in contour integrals so please bear with me :)

Mathematica assumes the principal branch of $\sqrt z$ with $\arg z\in(-\pi,\pi)$. I guess  that ContourIntegrate computes the integral along $|z|=1$ but joins the points at $\arg z=\pm\pi$ with a path that avoids the branch cut on the negative real axis; like this but in the opposite direction. Documentation is not clear on how integration is carried out with multivalued functions.

Thanks @user170231, I appreciate your comments; they have been helpful for me to understand how to get results in Mathematica (using the polar representation). I am looking for a way to solve this by hand eventually, so those closed forms will help me know when my derivation is correct :) work in progress...

On second thought, it seems more likely that Mma is not using the residue theorem at all, rather directly computing the line integral along $|z|=1$ on the assumed branch. With $z=e^{it}$ the integral reduces to$$i\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{dt}{1-2\sqrt r \cos\frac t2}$$
